Find next value in list of objects
I have a table, let's call it quotation_lines, like this:



Quote No
Product
Date Effective
Price




Q1
ABC
1-Jan-20
10.00


Q1
ABC
1-Mar-20
15.00


Q1
ABC
1-Dec-20
20.00


Q1
ABC
1-Mar-21
10.00


Q2
ABC
1-Feb-22
13.5



And I want to create an object like:
public class QuoteLine{
    public string QuoteNo {get;set;}
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public DateOnly DateEffective {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public DateOnly NextDate {get;set;}
    public decimal NextPrice {get;set;}
}


The question is, how do I get the next row of data to populate my object?  So for example, when I am considering the first row of data, my object would end up as
{
    "QuoteNo": "Q1",
    "Product": "ABC",
    "DateEffective": "1-Jan-20",
    "Price": 10,
    "NextDate": "1-Mar-20",
    "NextPrice": 15
}

And for the second row it would be
{
    "QuoteNo": "Q1",
    "Product": "ABC",
    "DateEffective": "1-Mar-20",
    "Price": 15,
    "NextDate": "1-Dec-20",
    "NextPrice": 20
}

And so on.
For the avoidance of doubt, this will be grouped by the quote number and the product.
If it's easier to do it by creating a view on the db, that's fine, but I have been struggling with that for about 4 hours now, and I can't work that out either.
Any assistance greatly appreciated.

I don't really understand the difficulty. If you have set up EF correctly then you simply do something like var db = new YourContextName(); var quoteLines = db.QuoteLines.ToArray();. the quoteLines var is now an array of 5 objects and you can do whatever with it, sort it in some way and then loop it to establish the notion of "Next" as index+1. Next is contextual to the order of a collection of objects, and you should avoid assigning meaning based on order as it can change easily.  If the question is about producing JSON, serialize the array eg JsonSerializer.Serialize(quoteLines)

How to get the "next" item in a list is wholly dependent on how you got the list and how you got the current item, neither of which you have made any attempt to explain. Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Use SQL LEAD. EF's LINQ will not help to do that effectively.

Easiest way : dt.AsEnunerable(),Select(x => ......)  x is each row of the datatable.  I usually use : foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable()){ ....... })

The question is unclear. This appears to be a LEAD / LAG problem, which EF Core 8 cannot solve easily to my knowledge. There is another ORM project  linq2db which can be used to fill in areas where EF is weak. Alternatively you can just write a raw SQL query / view and use EF to perform the mapping.
The linq2db query which appears to solve your request. Note: linq2db can be used without EF Core as a standalone ORM. It has scaffolding and a host of other features listed on their GitHub readme.
connection
    .GetTable<QuoteLine>()
    .Select(q => new
    {
        q.QuoteNo,
        q.Product,
        q.DateEffective,
        q.Price,
        NextDate = Sql.Ext.Lead(q.DateEffective)
            .Over().PartitionBy(q.QuoteNo).OrderBy(q.DateEffective).ToValue(),
        NextPrice = Sql.Ext.Lead(q.Price)
            .Over().PartitionBy(q.QuoteNo).OrderBy(q.DateEffective).ToValue(),
    })
    .ToList()

// SELECT
//     [q].[QuoteNo],
//     [q].[Product],
//     [q].[DateEffective],
//     [q].[Price],
//     LEAD([q].[DateEffective]) OVER(PARTITION BY [q].[QuoteNo] ORDER BY [q].[DateEffective]),
//     LEAD([q].[Price]) OVER(PARTITION BY [q].[QuoteNo] ORDER BY [q].[DateEffective])
// FROM
//     [quotation_lines] [q]

Below is the full program source showing the minimal configuration and setup required to reuse your EF Core model in linq2db.
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using LinqToDB;
using LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

// linq2db Nuget Packages added (License: MIT)
// <PackageReference Include="linq2db" Version="5.4.1" />
// <PackageReference Include="linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.1.0" />

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // So you can see the SQL generated by linq2db
        LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.TurnTraceSwitchOn();
        LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.WriteTraceLine = (message, _, _) => Console.WriteLine(message);
        
        using (var context = new SalesContext())
        using (var connection = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection())
        {
            var output = connection
                .GetTable<QuoteLine>()
                .Select(q => new
                {
                    q.QuoteNo,
                    q.Product,
                    q.DateEffective,
                    q.Price,
                    NextDate = Sql.Ext.Lead(q.DateEffective)
                        .Over().PartitionBy(q.QuoteNo).OrderBy(q.DateEffective).ToValue(),
                    NextPrice = Sql.Ext.Lead(q.Price)
                        .Over().PartitionBy(q.QuoteNo).OrderBy(q.DateEffective).ToValue(),
                })
                .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(output, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
        }
    }
}

public class SalesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<QuoteLine> QuoteLines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Sales;Trusted_Connection=True");

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        => configurationBuilder.Properties<decimal>().HavePrecision(18, 2);
}

[Table("quotation_lines")]
public class QuoteLine
{
    public long Id { get; set; } // EF Needs a PrimaryKey, so I added this
    [MaxLength(100)] public string QuoteNo { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateOnly DateEffective { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}


Thank you so much for taking the time to go into such detail for me, I really appreciate it.  I have not tested the code above, but once you put me onto the LEAD function, the answer was very simple to implement in a database view.
